# tar trying to open instead of create an archive

Tags: gzip, tar

I'm trying to run a command like this to back up my public directory:

```
tar -zcvf backups/2014-09-09-public_html.tar.gz public_html -C home/path
```

My understanding is that this is supposed to create and an archive with the compressed contents of my public directory. But I'm getting the following errors:

```
tar (child): backups/2014-09-09-public_html.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
```

This has me confused because I want it to create the file, not open it. I've used similar commands in other projects without problems, so I'm not sure what the problem could be here. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a file, you actually open it in write mode, even if it does not yet exist (read `man 3 open` to further understand how this works on *nix).

Are you sure you have write permissions for the destination where you're trying to compress? Can you `touch(1)` that location?

Comment: Yeah, I can touch the location. I also do a mysqldump there and it creates the file just fine

Comment: So ```touch backups/2014-09-09-public_html.tar.gz``` works fine? Looks like my assumption was wrong in that case, sorry.

Comment: Well you gave me part of the answer I was looking for. Now I know why it was trying to open the file, so +1 for that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it working by putting -C /home/path at the beginning and using the absolute path for the archive name instead of the relative path:

```
tar -C /home/path -zcvf /home/path/backups/2014-09-09-public_html.tar.gz public_html
```

I still don't understand why I need to specify the absolute path for the archive name since I've always used the relative path in other projects. I guess maybe it's a difference in how this server is set up or something?

Comment: The path is relative to your current directory. "home/path" needs to exist in the current directory for it to work, OR your current directory must be "/".